# Localhost in IIS7 works correctly in Firefox, but not in Chrome, why?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, iis-7

I have set up a site in IIS7 running on localhost for testing, this is running on port:80. Within this site there is a service application (also running on port:80).  When I access http://localhost/ via Firefox, the site comes up as it should. When I access the site with Chrome, I get the IIS7 welcome screen.

I'm baffled?!  Another SO post mentioned virtualhosts, but having a service as an application within a site on the same port shouldn't cause this - should it?

Help appreciated.

Comment: What is your default document name? Do you have one set?

Comment: default.aspx and yes, IIS is configured to accept default.aspx as the first default.

Comment: If you delete the IIS 7 welcome page, what happens?

Comment: It worked! :D No suddenly I think this might have something to do with the cache despite clearing it.... tomasmcguiness, can you chuck in an answer so I can mark it as the answer? :) +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the IIS 7 welcome page, what happens?

Comment: Seems to have been a cache problem. Deleting the page forced the browser to re-try the server proper and drop the cache. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Chrome has proxy-server set.

Comment: Nope. Neither worked :( I have two possible wireless connections, public & private.  Chrome is currently set to 'Automatically detect settings' for the connection, but even if I specify the proxy details and use public or private - I still get the IIS7 welcome screen. But never in Firefox? Thanks for the answer however :)